# Execute a synchronous function after an async function finishes?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I searched this on forum, but couldn't find an exact answer. The answers I tried doesn't give the result for me as explained. Callbacks are suggested, promises are suggested and also async functions are told to be used as promises. The question is simple, I have an async func, and I want it to finish for another func to be executed. For example:

```
const asyncFunc = async() => {
 try{
   await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.id), {token: null}).then(dispatch(SET_USER(null))).then(setUser(null))
 } catch(error) {
   console.log("ERROR -->",error)
 }
}
asyncFunc()
```

this results with error,

```
ERROR --> [TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined]
```

which means user is set to null before updateDoc finished, not as expected. Can you clarify how this can exactly be achieved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: @David I used setTimeout just for a sample usage of async function. Is'nt it an async?

Comment: You used `setTimeout`, but your "sleep" function is improperly implemented.  The linked duplicate shows correct implementations.  In your case that `asyncFunc` function doesn't do anything to internally await the timeout or wrap that timeout in a Promise.  So while the function itself is awaitable, the Promise it returns is essentially a no-op.  Check the linked duplicate for how to wrap a `setTimeout` in a `Promise` for a "sleep" function.

Comment: @David What you mean is I exactly should use "new Promise()" syntax for this purpose in the question? Consider my setTimeout example to be just an ordinary async function

Comment: *"I exactly should use "new Promise()" syntax for this purpose in the question?"* - Yes, your "sleep" function should wrap the `setTimeout` in a `Promise` and return that `Promise`.  The proposed duplicate has examples of this.  *"Consider my setTimeout example to be just an ordinary async function"* - Your `asyncFunc` is indeed an async function.  It's just not internally awaiting that timeout.  You're invoking your function correctly, the function itself just isn't doing what you want.

Comment: @David I didn't understand what you mean by "It's just not internally awaiting that timeout.". Can you clarify? Or how to implement await usage for that timeout?

Comment: *"Or how to implement await usage for that timeout?"* - The proposed duplicate has exactly that.  It provides multiple implementations of awaitable "sleep" functions in JavaScript by wrapping a timeout in a Promise.  You are encouraged to take a look.

Comment: @David I looked, but I am confused about this answer is spesific only for setTimeout method or for all async methods?

Comment: Well, your *question* is specific to using `setTimeout` within an `async` function to make the timeout awaitable.  So an *answer* which is specific to doing exactly that would be what you're looking for.  The proposed duplicate has such answers.  It's really not clear to me what's confusing about this.  For example, your function could be: `const asyncFunc = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => { console.log("Sleep finished"); r(); }, 5000))`

Comment: @David I am writing what exactly I try to do. I try to use Firebase's async updateDoc function-------> await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", loggedInProfile?.id), {token: null}).then(dispatch(SET_USER(null))).then(setUser(null)) but this doesn't result in my expected order. The then()s execute before updateDoc() function exeecutes. Sorry for plain writing since I don't know to convert to code appearance in comments

Comment: This code is very different from what you asked about in the question above.  If you're trying to solve a problem with this code, you are encouraged to ask a question about this code, in which you describe the problem and what debugging you have done.  The question above has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @David That's why I told considering the setTimeout method to be an ordinary async function. The question's main point is not about setTimeout, main point is executing synchronous function after async function finishes, just like the title

Comment: That's all well and good, but if the code you're asking about isn't the code you're trying to fix then I suggest you correct that.  The code in the question is corrected by wrapping `setTimeout` in a `Promise`, as demonstrated in the proposed duplicate.  Maybe the actual code you're using is also performing an asynchronous operation with a non-awaitable function and needs to be wrapped in a `Promise`?  Maybe something else is wrong with the actual code you're using?  (For example, the code in your previous comment incorrectly uses callbacks, which the code in the question correctly uses.)

Comment: @David Ok David, I am editing the question with my exactly intended usage, removing the setTimeout method. I've read more about docs for firebase, but usage of a sync call after execution of it is not mentioned

Comment: You didn't pass *callback* functions to your `then` calls. Instead you immediately *execute* functions (such as `dispatch` and `setUser`) and their return value is pass as argument to the `then` calls, but these return values are no functions. You should really pass callbacks. Or why not stick with `await` all together, and replace your `then` calls with `await`?

Comment: @trincot I commented to your answer, I think here await is not applicable. You wrote "You should really pass callbacks.", how can I do that exactly? I think using callback is necessary in this situation, not await method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...which means user is set to null before `updateDoc` finished

Indeed, you call `setUser` immediately. You're not *passing* as a function to be executed when the promise resolves, but execute it on the spot. The `then` method calls should receive a callback as argument.

But you can make it all easier, if you perform your actions below the `await` instead of those `then` calls:

```
await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", user.id), {token: null});
dispatch(SET_USER(null));
setUser(null);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but since dispatch() and setUser() are not async functions, vscode gives warning of -------> 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)

Comment: Yes. Corrected. The point is to execute those functions after the promise is resolved.

Comment: So, how to execute those functions after the promise is resolved?

Comment: Any code that follows *below* the `await` is executed after the promise (returned by `updateDoc()`) is resolved.

Comment: thank you @trincot, this info is important